# Open H and C files as text files in browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, file-types, mime-types

I'm using Firefox. When I come across a source file I want to examine, Firefox performs a download of the file. Then I have to wait 5 or 10 seconds for Xcode to spin up. For example, [`genks.c`](http://www.gat3way.eu/poc/wep/genks.c).

I'd like to view the source files in the browser to save the time (if I need the file, I'll right click and select download). However, Firefox only provides "Always Ask" and "Open with External Application [sic]" (interestingly, I am not prompted even though that's the setting):

[image]

Does Firefox allow one to view files in the browser as text files?

How does one instruct Firefox to open H and C files as text files in the browser?

Comment: While looking for an answer to this very problem, I found that it's something that's been [flagged as an issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57342)...some 15 *years* ago!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Firefox, whereby it doesn't treat `text/X` (where `X` is unknown to it) as `text/plain` and forces you to either save the file or open it in something else.

The [Open in Browser extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) partially solves this problem, by allowing you to choose to open any file with an unknown media type in the browser as something else (e.g., text, HTML, etc.) However, it won't remember the decision you made for a specific media type and you have to go through the motions every time you try to open such a file.